# How should I put 'threshold' argument in my below script,

Tags: r

I am using METAN package for data analysis, getting this error of Column 'GEN' has more levels (274) than the threshold (15) allowed. How should I increse the 'threshold' in my below script?

```
> library(metan)
> data <- read.csv("D:/Biostst Analysis/###metan Analysis/Aphid_ORF.csv", header = TRUE)
> # Convert variables into appropriate data types
> data$GEN<-as.factor(data$GEN)  # GEN. as factor
> data$REP<-as.factor(data$REP)  # REP. as factor
> data$ENV<-as.factor(data$ENV)  # Env. as factor
> # Order the factor levels
> data$ENV<- factor(data$ENV, 
+                             levels = c("E1","E2"))
> inspect(data, plot = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 × 10
  Variable Class   Missing Levels Valid_n   Min Median   Max Outlier Text 
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <int> <lgl>
1 GEN      factor  No      274       1644    NA     NA    NA      NA NA   
2 REP      factor  No      3         1644    NA     NA    NA      NA NA   
3 ENV      factor  No      2         1644    NA     NA    NA      NA NA   
4 ORF      integer No      -         1644     2      5     8     133 NA   
Error: Column 'GEN' has more levels (274) than the threshold (15) allowed.
Please remove the column or increase the 'threshold' argument. Increasing the threshold may produce long processing times
In addition: Warning message:
Possible outliers in variable(s) ORF. Use 'find_outliers()' for more details.
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Your `GEN` column has 274 unique values, whereas the function you are using only allows for 15. A potential solution could be to combine certain `GEN` values into groups. However, from looking at your code, it seems `GEN` is an ID column anyway that you probably don't want to throw into your analysis.

Comment: After your question update  - did you actually check the help for the `inspect` function? It describes precisely this `threshold` argument which might solve your problem.

Comment: Dear @descgen, I have edited my question, can you please address this once again. I am a beginner in the R, so could you please elaborate on the solution then I will be grateful.

Comment: You should first check the help function of inspect, i.e. with `?metan::inspect`. There, you'll find some information about the `threshold` argument. You can then add/specify it similar to the `plot = TRUE` argument. Give it a try, if it doesn't work, please update your questions with how you tried to set the threshold parameter and then we can see what needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you very much Dear....! it worked with Help. 
inspect(.data, ..., plot = FALSE, threshold = 300, verbose = TRUE)